# Ajax , html5, Fancybox.js

Tags: ajax, html, fancybox

I am having problems with using Ajax and Fancybox.js photo viewer together.

I have a website set up first as web 1.0 with the standard navigation with hyperlinks.

but for html5 browsers I'm am using javascript that creates a web 2.0 experience.

The javascript first highjacks the links onclick event which makes a XMLHttpRequest that calls a php script that parses the html and sends back just the part of the html that I want to replace. I am using pushState and popState to get the back and forward buttons to function.

It is working great, it creates the Ajax effect, while persevering all the advantages of web 1.0 including SEO, because the links as far as the search engine spiders are concerned the links are just standard links to standard html pages.

The problem is that one of the pages uses Fancybox.js to show photos, it works fine when the page is accessed via the standard url, but when the html is accessed via the Ajax scripts if breaks it.

Here is code for the Ajax,

```
if (history.pushState) {

function changeContent(url) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getContents.php?url=" + url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}





$(document).ready(function() {
    var elems = null,
        links = null,
        link = null,
        i;

    elems = document.getElementById('nav');
    links = elems.getElementsByTagName('a');

    if (links) {
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    url = $(this).attr("href");
                    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
                    var n = pathArray.length;
                    changeContent(url);
                    history.pushState(null, null, url);
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var urlstr = window.location,
                    index = /index/g,
                    program = /program/g,
                    photos = /photos/g,
                    testimonials = /testimonials/g,
                    about = /about/g,
                    contact = /contact/g;

                    if (program.test(urlstr)){
                        changeCurrentPage('#program');
                        document.title = "Our Programs Kolibri Daycare";

                    }else if (photos.test(urlstr)){
                        changeCurrentPage('#photos');
                        document.title = "Photos Kolibri Daycare";
                        slideShow();

                    }else if (testimonials.test(urlstr)){
                        changeCurrentPage('#testimonials');
                        document.title = "Tesimonials Kolibri Daycare";

                    }else if (about.test(urlstr)){
                        changeCurrentPage('#about');
                        document.title = "About Kolibri Daycare";

                    }else if (contact.test(urlstr)){
                        changeCurrentPage('#contact');
                        document.title = "Contact Kolibri Daycare";
                    }else {
                        changeCurrentPage('#home');
                        document.title = "Kolibri Daycare";
                    }
                }, false);
            }
        }

        window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {

        var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
        var n = pathArray.length;
        if (pathArray[n-1]){
            changeContent(pathArray[n-1]);
        }else {
            changeContent('index.html');
        }
    }, false);
    }, 1);
});
}
```

and her is the script that calls Fancybox.js,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'overlayShow'   : false,
            'cyclic'        : true,
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic'
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

It is in the head section of the page.

When the html that has the photo links is brought in via Ajax the script that calls fancybox.js is not included. I have tried calling it in different places but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-initialize fancybox on the new elements added from ajax. I'm not sure why you don't just upgrade the entire page to HTML5 and use some of the ajax functions provided by jQuery, but I think the re-initialization should be inserted after this line (not tested!):

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
$('#content').find("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox();
```